# True or false.If the series converges for x=1.1, then it converges for x=7

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I saw this question in a previous year test and it seemed pretty simple, and that can often mean that I am missing something.

If the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-3)^n$$ converges for $x=-1.1$, then it converges for $x=7$.

So, by definition, I can say that this series converges for $\lvert x-3\rvert<r$,.

I can rewrite that as $-r+3<x<r+3$.

Since r must be greater than $0$, I solve for $r$ in the left side, as the right side would yield me a negative $r$, so that $-r+3=-1.1$, which yields $r=4.1$.

With this, I conclude that the series converges for $-1.1<r<7.1$ which makes the proposition true.

Is this procces right? Or am I missing something important?

Comment: Your idea seems solid, though you can't actually conclude that $r=4.1$ as you have written.  All you can get is that $r≥4.1$, but that is good enough to answer the question.

Comment: Oh thanks! I tend to do that. You're right, I should have concluded that for the series to converge at $x=-1.1$, the condition is that $r>=4.1$, and with that radius, the series will always converge for $x=7$.

Comment: Note that the ".1" is necessary. The same question with "-1.0" and "7" would be false -- the series would not necessarily converge.

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is not quite right because you did not solve the compound inequality correctly and you did not actually prove that $|x-3|<r$ for $x=7$.

Let's say we have the following, as you did:

$$-r+3 < x < r+3$$

Then, we need to solve this compound inequality for $x=-1.1$.

If $-r+3 < -1.1$, then $-r < -4.1$ and $r > 4.1$, or $4.1 < r$ If $-1.1 < r+3$, then $-4.1 < r$. Thus, these inequalities can be compounded to $-4.1 < 4.1 < r$ which can be simplified to $4.1 < r$.

Now, let's say $x=7$. If $x=7$, then $|x-3|=4$. Since $|x-3| < 4.1$ and $4.1 < r$, $|x-3|<r$, meaning the series converges for $x=7$, concluding the proof.

Comment: Thank for the answer! You're absolutely right, I tend to get a bit "informal" when trying to prove something. I'll work on that.

Answer (score 1):

The related theorem is that if a power series 
$$
\sum a_k(z-z_0)^k
$$
converges for some $z=z_1$ then it also converges for all $z$ with
$$
|z-z_0|<|z_1-z_0|.
$$
Here $z_0=3$, $z_1=-1.1$ so that convergence is guaranteed for $|z-3|<4.1$. $z=7$ satisfies this inequality.

---

Proof idea: The terms of the $z_1$ series converge to zero, thus are bounded by some $M$ and thus 
$$
|a_k(z-z_0)^k|\le M·\left|\frac{z-z_0}{z_1-z_0}\right|^k.
$$